# SQL Logic to return ONLY uppercase if matches Else it should return the lower case

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like below and then have a input parameter 'William'. 
So I need to match the input parameter with the Table1.Name with case sensitive. In case, if the Upper case name is not found then need to return the lower case.

```
Table1
ID  |  Name
1   |  William
2   |  WILLIAM
3   |  ROSE
4   |  Rose
```

I tried with the below query somehow its not giving expected result for all the cases.

```
Select * from 
  Table1
Where
    Table1.Name COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI =
          (CASE WHEN 'William' COLLATE  Latin1_General_BIN  LIKE '%[a-z]%' 
                   THEN UPPER('William') 
               ELSE 'William' END )
```

Comment: Please be clearer about what your actual results vs expected results are.

Comment: Do you need to have case sensitive querying often, or is this a one time event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your column currently has a case insensitive collation you can use

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM   Table1
WHERE  Name = 'William' 
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN Name = UPPER('William') COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
              THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END
```

As the collation is case insensitive it will bring back all variants of William. Ones matching "WILLIAM" will be scored 0 and ones matching any other variant as 1 and the `TOP 1 WITH TIES` retains the group with the lowest score that exists in the results.

Comment: Simply elegant.  Even supports LIKE

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `CASE WHEN` in `where clause`. You can by changing the `Collation`.

```
DECLARE @Input NVARCHAR(50) = 'William'

SELECT * 
FROM 
  Tbl T
WHERE
    T.Name = UPPER(@Input) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS OR 
    (
        NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1 FROM Tbl IT
            WHERE
                IT.Name = UPPER(@Input) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
        ) AND
        T.Name = @Input COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
    )
```